# Implementing jQuery Bootgrid error: Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, jquery-bootgrid

I'm implementing jQuery bootgrid with my ASP.Net MVC application. I'm just having an issue with the following code:

```
var tResult = BootgridResponseData<List<Contact>>()
    {
        current = model.current,
        rowCount = model.rowCount,
        rows = contacts,
        total = contacts.Count
    };
```

This gives me the following error:

> Non-invocable member 'BootgridResponseData' cannot be used like a method.

My `BootgridResponseData` class is defined as follows:

```
public class BootgridResponseData<T> where T : class
{
    public int current { get; set; } //? current page
    public int rowCount { get; set; } //? rows per page
    public IEnumerable<T> rows { get; set; } //? items
    public int total { get; set; } //? total rows for whole query
}
```

What might be wrong here? I'm not 100% sure what I'm doing right here because I've been guided into doing it this way so far.

Comment: you have missed initialisation, var tResult = new BootgridResponseData<List<Contact>>()

Comment: I don't know if it's in your actual code or if it's just in this question, but, are you missing the "new" keyword in the first line?

As in:
var tResult = new BootgridResponseData<List<Contact>>()
    {
        current = model.current,
        rowCount = model.rowCount,
        rows = contacts,
        total = contacts.Count
    };

Comment: Yes, that was it...